# iOS Table View click event not working

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

When i click table view cell click event not working. I am assigned the data to view in custom tableView cell class and passed the value from viewController class. Is there is any problem in assigning data to views in custom table view cell class

ViewController.class

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = self.ViewAllTableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ViewAllTableViewCell", for: indexPath) as! ViewAllTableViewCell

    let products = self.allProducts[indexPath.row]
    cell.setData(products: products)

    cell.delegate = self

    return cell
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    performSegue(withIdentifier: "allDetail", sender: self)

}

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if let destination = segue.destination as? ProductDetailViewController{

        let products = self.allProducts[(ViewAllTableView.indexPathForSelectedRow?.row)!]
        destination.productID = products.id

    }
}
```

This is Custom Table View Cell class

ViewAllTableViewCell.class

```
class ViewAllTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

@IBOutlet weak var ItemImage: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var ItemName: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var ItemOfferPrice: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var ItemOriginalPrice: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var ItemWeight: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var ItemCountLabel: UILabel!

var delegate : ViewAllTableViewCellDelegate?
var allProduct: ViewAllProductsData!

func setData(products: ViewAllProductsData){

    self.allProduct = products

    self.ItemName.text = allProduct.name
    self.ItemWeight.text = "\(allProduct.quantity) \(allProduct.unit)"
    self.ItemOfferPrice.text = "\(allProduct.price)"
    self.ItemOriginalPrice.text = "\(allProduct.originalPrice)"
    self.ItemCountLabel.text = "\(allProduct.count)"
    let url: URL = NSURL(string: allProduct.image)! as URL
    self.ItemImage.af_setImage(withURL: url)
}

@IBAction func ViewAllMinusButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
    delegate?.minusCount(data: allProduct)
}

@IBAction func ViewAllPlusbutton(_ sender: UIButton) {

    delegate?.addCount(data: allProduct)
}

}
protocol ViewAllTableViewCellDelegate{
    func addCount(data: ViewAllProductsData)
    func minusCount(data: ViewAllProductsData)
}
```

Comment: Make sure that you have set `UITableViewDelegate` properly.

Comment: have you set tableview.delegate = self anywhere in your class?

Comment: Tried but still not working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It worked for me after changing tableView attribute selection from no selection to single selection

Answer (score 4):

It happens because either you haven't conform properly to `UITableViewDelegate` or you have `UITapGestureRecognizer` somewhere in your view controller.